# function setInterval next() with active/remove class

Tags: jquery

I tried to remove class and add class to the next element with setInterval fonction

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 setInterval(function() {
   var active = $('li').hasClass('active');
  active.removeClass('active');
    active.next('li').addClass('active');
 }, 3000);
});
```

```css
li.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class='active'>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this `var active = $('li.active');`

**Working demo**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var active = $('li.active');
    active.removeClass('active');
    if (active.next('li').length == 0) {
      active.parent('ul').find('li:first').addClass('active');
    } else {
      active.next('li').addClass('active');
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
li.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class='active'>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks;)  And how to loop list ?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this for loop liste :

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 setInterval(function() {
   if ($('li').last().hasClass('active')) {
     $('li').first().addClass('actie');
      $('li').last().removeClass('active');
    } else {
      var active = $('li.active');
      active.next('li').addClass('active');
      active.removeClass('active');
    }
 }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.list.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class='list active'>list item 1</li>
  <li class='list'>list item 2</li>
  <li class='list'>list item 3</li>
  <li class='list'>list item 4</li>
  <li class='list'>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is the condition doesn't work. I've tried with this $('li.active').is(':last-child') but sames result.

Comment: Sorry, juste missing V on 'active' in this line $('li').first().addClass('actie');